# Why can we only observe Bragg Peaks when h, k and l are integers?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

When studying Bragg's law, if we assume a cubic lattice, we can write the equation as 
$$ \frac{2a \sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2+l^2}} = n\lambda $$
Given a value for $\lambda$ , my professor said that we only observe Bragg Peaks in Diffraction experiments when h, k and l are integers, and I am unable to see why. Why is this so?

Comment: Only then may scattering contributions from different atoms contribute in phase to cause constructive interference.

Comment: Do the 1d case again and follow the derivation.